# How To Disable Subsonic's Primary Key Autoincrement?

Tags: c#, subsonic, primary-key, auto-increment

I'm using Subsonic (simplerepository) and SQLite, and I have a class with an Int64 property marked as [SubSonicPrimaryKey]:

```
[SubSonicPrimaryKey]    
public Int64 MyID;
```

which is transformed into:

`[MyID] integer  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Is it possible to disable the AUTOINCREMENT feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found it by myself. Autoincrement feature is automatic and cannot be switched off. Here's what the code does:

```
        if(column.IsPrimaryKey)
        {
            sb.Append(" NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY");
            if(column.IsNumeric)
                sb.Append(" AUTOINCREMENT ");
        }
```